# Setting and Getting with Java Hashmaps

Tags: java, hashmap

I'd like to create a HashMap with two String values. The first string value is of some "Mode" and the second string value is of some "State" for example:

"TRACK" mode is "DISABLED"

I would like to create a HashMap with multiple defined modes, with a "State" associated with each that changes from "ENABLED" or "DISABLED".  This is what I have so far:

```
public class SystemModeStatus{

    private Map<String String> map = new HashMap<String,String>(){
        {
        put("MODE_A", "STATE");
        put("MODE_B", "STATE");
        put("MODE_C", "STATE");
        }
    };

    public SystemModeStatus(Map<String, String> m){
        this.map = m;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getMap(){
        return this.map;
    }
}
```

Now what I would like to do is retrieve/set the "State" of each "Mode". However I can't seem to find the proper syntax.. am I approaching this correctly? Is there somethind I'm doing wrong that is complicating my process?

Thank you.

Comment: why a map and not an enum?

Comment: You are supposed to write a getter and a setter. In the setter, write code that puts the given value in the given key in the map, and in the getter, return the value in the given key in the map. Do you know how to use maps at all?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You define a private map and then don't use it but just overwrite it in the constructor.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ it can be a map of enum keys to enum values, but I don't see how you can avoid using a map if you want to change the state (unless you suggest that it would be done globally in a static in the enum, which I wouldn't recommend).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you should probably remove the `getMap()` method as you want to expose as few methods as possible on the internal map.

Then you can add methods to update the values in your map:

```
public void set(String mode, String status) {
    this.map.put(mode, status);
}

public String getStatus(String mode) {
    return this.map.get(mode);
}
```

More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: This helped a lot. The put method cleaned up my error. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get "State" of each "Mode" you can use foreach if you're using java8 else you can use an iterator :

```
  public static void printState(Map mp) {
        Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println("State : "+ pair.getValue());

        }
    }
```

in your Main class for exemple you can do :

```
 SystemModeStatus systemModeStatue = new  SystemModeStatus()
 printState(systemModeStatue.getMap());
```